# iPhone Copy Something to Clipboard via Code

Tags: iphone, copy

I was wondering if I could copy some text to the iphone keyboard via code - I.E. They press a button named "Copy Link to Clipboard" and it would copy a link to the Clipboard?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "to the keyboard"?

Comment: I think he means "clipboard", like in the question title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Text to Clipboard (Pasteboard) from UITextView via UIButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522512/copy-text-to-clipboard-pasteboard-from-uitextview-via-uibutton)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A normal string would be copied via

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.string = @"my test string";
```

a URL via e.g

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060471/iphone-copy-something-to-clipboard-via-code"];
```

Answer (score 4):

`UIPasteboard` is what you need:

http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-3-copy-paste-with-uipasteboard/

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "This is the copied text"
```